# Grails - URL mappings with empy-valued path param

Tags: grails, url-mapping, urlmappings.groovy

In my Grails 4 web-app defined 2 URL mappings

```
"/projects" ( controller: 'team', action: 'listProjects' )
"/projects/$projectid" ( controller: 'team', action: 'getProject' )
```

When, in the 2nd mapping, `projectid` param is erroneously passed as “” (empty string), the `listProjects` action is processed instead of `getProject` (the intended one).
Is there a way to do that? I'd actually want a "project not found" error to be returned in place of the list of projects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try swapping the order of your entries in url mappings?

Comment: I did tried inverting the 2 mappings declaration, or using the optional setting for the path param `"/projects/$projectid?"`, but had the same outcome.

A little trick came to my mind this morning: by checking `request.forwardURI` in “listProjects”, if it has a trailing `/` than I can forward to “getProject”. Not the cleanest solution I guess, but at least it'd do…